# YamlDotNet doesn't support deserializing KeyValuePair<,> types

Tags: c#, .net, yaml, yamldotnet

I've got a scenario in which I need to deserialize a sequence of maps to `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` that wouldn't be solved by simply using `Dictionary<string, string>` instead. Since, apparently, YamlDotNet doesn't support `KeyValuePair<,>` out of the box, what alternative solutions could I rely on?

Example YAML:

```yaml
- key1: value1
- key2: value2
- key3: value3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [issue here](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/issues/249) states that `KeyValuePair<,>` isn't, nor is it going to be, supported, according to **aaubry**, the owner of YamlDotNet. Yet, he does further state, in his response under the same issue, that it can be easily implemented by adding a custom `INodeDeserializer`. Since the example he included isn't applicable, however, I'll provide a more accurate implementation here.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using YamlDotNet.Core;
using YamlDotNet.Core.Events;
using YamlDotNet.Serialization;


internal class KeyValuePairNodeDeserializer : INodeDeserializer
{
    public bool Deserialize(IParser parser, Type expectedType, Func<IParser, Type, object> nestedObjectDeserializer, out object value)
    {
        if (expectedType.IsGenericType && expectedType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(KeyValuePair<,>))
        {
            parser.Consume<MappingStart>();

            var pairArgs = expectedType.GetGenericArguments();

            object key = null;
            object val = null;

            if (parser.Accept<Scalar>(out _))
                key = nestedObjectDeserializer(parser, pairArgs[0]);

            if (parser.Accept<Scalar>(out _))
                val = nestedObjectDeserializer(parser, pairArgs[1]);

            value = Activator.CreateInstance(expectedType, key, val);

            parser.Consume<MappingEnd>();
            return true;
        }

        value = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now you can register your custom `INodeDeserializer` like below:

```cs
var deserializer = new DeserializerBuilder()
    .WithNodeDeserializer(new KeyValuePairNodeDeserializer())     // Register here.
    .WithNamingConvention(UnderscoredNamingConvention.Instance)
    .Build();
```